# jQuery Deferred object centralized global error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Errors that happen inside Deferred object throws a warning in to the console and not getting noticed in:

```
    window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
       // Global handler
    });
```

How to make centralized error handler work for all errors including Deferred object?

I am using most recent jQuery 3.3.1 and couldn't find woking solution.

Comment: @MaorRefaeli, it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [jQuery 3.3.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) *(line 3605)*, they actually have implemented `$.Deferred.exceptionHook` to be called when deferred object fails.

And for your case, you just need to implement it like,

```
$.Deferred.exceptionHook = function (err, stackTrace) {
  // 'err' is what you throw in your deferred's catch.
  window.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('error', {
    detail: err
  }) );
}
```

Here's some simple example.

```js
$.Deferred.exceptionHook = function (err, stackTrace) {
  // 'err' is what you throw in your deferred's catch.
  $("#errorMessage").text(err);
}

$.when(
  $.ajax( "https://example.com" ) // This should fail since SO is sandboxed.
).then(function successFn() {
  alert("Impossible thing is happening");
}, function failFn() {
  throw "A nice error";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<p id="errorMessage">
  
</p>
```

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: @Jonas Just so you know, I can't find any related documentation for this. You might want to consider twice before using this approach as this might change in the future. But imo, this should work in your current version.

Comment: related ticket for exceptionHook https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/3198

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery for ajax requests you could do:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(){
   console.log(arguments);
}
```